# Integrating another framework with polymer dart 1.0

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Apologies if this is a bit fuzzy.

I have my own FRP based library for building my application models. It has a concept of `components` which have `state` which is changed via `Stream`s.

This encapsulates the behaviour of the UI minus the actual views. I am starting to integrate this with Polymer 1.0 and would like some guidance as the the best approach.

Some things are easy (like binding changes to fields in my models to `notifyPath`).

For updates I'm considering having a single method with an `Observe` annotation like

```
@Observe('*')
void myHandler(Map changeRecord) => ... delegate to my adapters
```

Is it likely to be inefficient to listen to all (*) events like this? Is there a lower level way to register more specific paths that avoids the need for the `Observe` annotation?

Is using the `PolymerRegister` annotation the best way to register the components in this case? Is there lower level API to do it instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it likely to be inefficient to listen to all (*) events like this?

The global * event is not actually supported unfortunately, the path must start with a property name. You could make a behavior which uses the `properties` getter to set up manual listeners on all properties.

> Is there a lower level way to register more specific paths that avoids the need for the Observe annotation.

There is the `listen(Node element, String eventName, String methodName)` method. You can just pass `this` as the node and listen to `{{property}}-changed` events. You will need to make sure all your properties have `notify: true` so they fire the events. This is also going to be a little less efficient since it is using actual events instead of the magic hooks which observers use.

There are probably some other hacks to dynamically add regular observers, but I don't know of them off the top of my head :).

> Is using the PolymerRegister annotation the best way to register the components in this case? Is there lower level API to do it instead?

This is the only way today, but if you wanted to control when the registration happens you could just create a `const PolymerRegister(...)` object and call `initialize` on it whenever your heart desires. Please file a feature request for a real imperative api if you would prefer that.

Comment: Thanks Jake. The '*' was just a hack. I actually know all the paths that I want to listen to, I'm just trying to avoid having to create wrapper methods with `Observe` annotations for all of them.
I will take a look at behaviours and see if that get around that.

Comment: Do you mean this getter in PolymerBase (`js.JsObject get properties => jsElement['properties'];`)?

BTW can I simply create properties via an API and bypass the `@Property` annotation? Is that a cleaner way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Yes, that is the getter I was referring to. Now that you mention it though we should probably be calling `convertToDart` before returning that so it is a Map and you can iterate its keys.

You could create properties programatically if you bypass the `PolymerRegister` annotation and do element registration manually. See the undocumented but public `createPolymerDescriptor` method. You could add any items to the `properties` key of the returned object, and then manually register that with polymer in the same way that `PolymerRegister` does (see `PolymerRegister.initialize`).

Comment: Thanks Jake. I started playing around with my own version of `PolymerRegister` with my own version of `createPolymerDescriptor` last night and will continue that today and see how it goes.

Comment: BTW if you did call `convertToDart ` on `properties` would it's keys be the property name and the values `Property` objects?